# Php mysql connection with PDO on IIS

Tags: php, mysql, iis, pdo

The following code on execution shows :

> could not find driver.

I have already changed extension=`php_pdo_mysql.dll` from comment and also restarted the server but it still shows *driver couldn't found.*
I'm using `mysql5.7` `php 7.1.6` and `iis10`.

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=stickercollections",$username,$password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stickercollections";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
    echo $row["collection_brand"] ." - ". $row["collection_year"] ."<br/>";
    }


    $dbh = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled the extension in php.ini .
Also check PHP info and verify that the extension is indeed installed. This can be done by creating a file called info.php in the htdocs folder with the following content

```
<?php
      phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: what to check there?

Comment: Check if PDO is listed there or not